# Show LevelListDrawable on Notification Bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to show a icon on the notification bar.
The icon is a LevelListDrawable which could change the content by setting levels.
The question is I can't set level to the icon in the notification.
I have tried to use "Notification.icon" and "Notification.iconLevel" but it's not works.

Here is my code fragment. can anyone see what's wrong?

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_notify;
notification.iconLevel = 30;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Hello", "World", intent);
manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Here is my LevelListDrawable

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_0"
        android:minLevel="0"
        android:maxLevel="9"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_10"
        android:minLevel="10"
        android:maxLevel="11"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_20"
        android:minLevel="20"
        android:maxLevel="29"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_30"
        android:minLevel="30"
        android:maxLevel="39"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_40"
        android:minLevel="40"
        android:maxLevel="49"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_50"
        android:minLevel="50"
        android:maxLevel="59"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_60"
        android:minLevel="60"
        android:maxLevel="69"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_70"
        android:minLevel="70"
        android:maxLevel="79"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_80"
        android:minLevel="80"
        android:maxLevel="89"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_90"
        android:minLevel="90"
        android:maxLevel="99"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_stat_notify_100"
        android:minLevel="100"
        android:maxLevel="100"/>
</level-list>
```

Comment: could you please post your level-list xml?

Comment: I found the icon on the status bar is correct with the level. But it's incorrect in the notification view in the drawer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a certain icon for the notification in the expanded notifications list, you should create the notification with a "normal" drawable without iconLevel and on first update you can set another icon (a level-list ex.) and set the iconLevel.

For updating the icon in the status bar

```
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_notify;
    notification.iconLevel = 30;
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

it's important to call notify() to make updates visible, and won't update the icon in the expanded list, unless you recreate the notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of this:
[android Notification setSmallIcon with level-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564650/android-notification-setsmallicon-with-level-list)

It appears to be a bug in Android.  When updating a notification with a level list, the status bar icon updates, but the icon in the notification pulldown does not.  It has been reported here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43179&q=setSmallIcon&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars