# android Notification setSmallIcon with level-list

Tags: android, statusbar, android-notifications

I am using Notification.Builder to create a notification. For this notification I am using a level-list as the small Icon

```
mNotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_levellist, levelInt);
```

This sets the icon to the correct level in the status bar, however when pulling down the notification the icon is set to the default level.

I have tried using a custom layout in order to display this and it works, however I would like to be able to use the default layout that comes with Notification.Builder.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Could you share some of your code for the custom implementation? I haven't been able to get this working.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a bug as I am experiencing the same thing
You can star this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=43179&q=setSmallIcon&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars